# How to force update data cache in react-apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

How to `refetch` fresh data when you revisit a page whose data is powered by `react-apollo`?

Say, I visit a listing page for the first time. `apollo` will fetch the query and caches it by default. So, when you visit the same page again during the session, it will populate the data from its cache store. How to force `apollo` to refetch data every time when the component mounts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `apollo`'s [fetchPolicy](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy). Based on this, it will decide to execute the query or not **again**.

Example:

```
const graphQLOptions = {
  name: 'g_schemas',
  options: (props) => {
    return {
      variables: {
        name: props.name,
      },
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    }
  },
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Pranesh's answer: the `fetchPolicy` you're looking for is `network-only`.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using `react-apollo`'s Query component, for example:

```
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
```

You can apply the fetchPolicy through its props. See below an example:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import React from 'react';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

const CounterView = ({ counter }) => (
  <div>{counter}</div>
);

const GET_COUNTER = gql`
  {
    counter
  }
`;

const Counter = () => (
  <Query query={GET_COUNTER} fetchPolicy={'network-only'}>
    {({ data }) => {
      return <CounterView {...data} />;
    }}
  </Query>
);

export default Counter;
```

References:

- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#basic
- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#props
- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy